# Display div on hover and keep it displayed

Tags: css, hover

I have a div which is to be shown on hover of another div, but on hovering out it gets hidden again. I am trying **not to hide the div on hover out**,  with the help of *CSS* but not getting a way.

```
a:hover b {
  opacity : 1
}

a:unhover b {
  opacity : 1
}
```

The `div` element is shown only after hover, but should not get hidden on hover out.

Comment: show us what you've achieved? your code?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle to make it more clear?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

> I have used key frame animations to produce the desired result:

```css
@keyframes hoverdisplay {
  0% {
   
    opacity: 0;
    max-height:0;
 
  }
  100% {
    
    opacity: 1;

 
  }
}
 .hoverForever div {
  animation: hoverdisplay 1ms backwards paused;   
}
.hoverForever:hover > div {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running;

}

div {
  display: block;
 
  background: green;
   width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hoverForever">
Hover Me to show
   <div>I will stay forever !</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sELKu/152/
Please check this

```
#a:hover+ #b{
  display:block;
}
```

Updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sELKu/153/
Please check this
**CSS**

```
#a,
#b {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}
#b {
    margin-top: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0s 180s;
}
#a:hover+ #b {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0s;
}
#a {
    transition: 0s 180s;
}
```

Comment: No it wont help. Its usual hover, I need to keep #b displayed even after mouse leave on #a